# Substitute for apc_exists()

Tags: php, apc

I want to replace `Apc_bc` to `APCU`.

What I use `Apc_bc` now are just three function.

`apc_exists()`

`apc_fetch()`

`apc_store()`

then, now I found `apcu_fetch()` and `apc_store()`.

However I can't find the substitute for `apc_exists()`.

How can I solve it ??

`Environment - PHP7.3.8`

Comment: Tried the docs?  Looks like a straightforward replacement to me! https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apcu-exists.php

Comment: Thanks!! I just changed every apc -> apcu , it works

Comment: I'll raise the comment as a full answer for completeness - and you're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

php.net [contains a complete function list for APCU](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.apcu.php), which appears to closely reflect APC's (same function names, simply substituting `apc` with `apcu`).

The one you're looking for is (unimaginatively!) named [`apcu_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apcu-exists.php).

Comment: Promoted the comment thread to a full answer for completeness.